# How can I query Google App Engine entities by name to convert to new names?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I want to convert some Entities to new names. How can I query entities not having model class defined.

For example I have such entity (it simplified to be more readable):

```
class Some(ndb.model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I want to rename it to:

```
class SomeFile(ndb.model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

How can I do it?

If will rename `Some` to `SomeFile` there will be no more `Some` to query but only data in datastore.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your Model class name and have it point to an existing datastore `Kind` by overriding the Model's `_get_kind()` method.

```
class SomeFile(ndb.Model):
    @classmethod
    def _get_kind(cls):
      return 'Some'
```

Now you can use `SomeFile` in python code while retaining the `Some` entities in your datastore.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#introduction

Comment: That is some idea. Whatever I want top change all names to simplify code. I prefer that X is X more that X is Y.

Comment: Well you already deleted the old model names so that is your option or you can temporarily replace the old models to do the swap like the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand your question, but is this what you want?:

```
for x in Some.query():
    y = SomeFile()
    y.name = x.name
    y.put()
    x.key.delete()
```

Although you should make this more efficient by doing it in batches.

Comment: I can not work you are assuming that class Some is existing but will be replace and Some will be delete since dead code. I can not maintain dead code since it block development.

Comment: I don't understand your comment...  If `class Some()` doesn't exist then just create it as an Expando so you don't need to list out the properties.  After you convert, you delete this trivial definition of `class Some()` so you are not maintaining dead code.

Comment: It simple I can not have Some(ndb.Model) since this code must be delete after update not keep - consider that after 100 patch I will have 50 of Some(epxando) ... - that is problem to not keed dead things.