# How to read, update, delete entities in Google App Engine NOT models (ndb.Model or db.Model)?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I want to read, convert and delete some entities from datastore which does not have ndb.Model or db.Model classes. When I trying it with GQL it leads to:

```
KindError: No implementation for kind 'SomeModel'
```

I do not want to create 'SomeModel' class since it will create redundant classes I just want convert 'SomeModel' to 'SomeModelDifferentName' and delete old models. How can I do it?

Comment: Check out my answer to your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046465/how-can-i-query-google-app-engine-entities-by-name-to-convert-to-new-names) where you override the `classmethod` `_get_kind()`. That can help. One trick I have used in the past is to enable the interactive console (appstats) at `/_ah/stats/shell` and type in a temporary `ndb.Model` subclass with the Kind name you need. This also works for manipulating fields that may or may not exist in deployed code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer covering model migration.  It shows how to get the underlying entities from the datastore without creating models.

[Migrating data when changing an NDB field's property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842671/migrating-data-when-changing-an-ndb-fields-property-type/19848970#19848970)

Its a bit old now, but the fundamentals haven't changed much. If you have <100,000 entities I would do this via remote_api and save having to deploy any code.

Comment: I will read how to use datastore api - maybe thare so query option in it - looks promising but not checked.